Localhost web app on iOS works, but it can't fetch data from localhost server
I'm using MacOS for development and I'm able to load my localhost web app on my iPhone over the lightning cable.
Strangely, I can't make localhost requests to my local Firebase instance (so frontend works, but network requests not).
Web app is on port :5555
Functions server on port :5005
Should I turn something on/off? Firewall is turned off so that for sure is not the case. On my desktop all works properly.
The only error I get from the mobile devtools (provided via desktop Safari dev options) is:
Failed to load resource: Can't connect to the server
and
ERR_NETWORK from Axios error log
